# Create view - Pass parameter and update model vie Stored Procedure

Tags: javascript, json, model-view-controller

How would I pass a parameter from a view, run a stored procedure and update specific model values on the same view, then be able to change those values if needed and save them. Here is what I am trying, get results from a SP and return them back (as an alert just to test). First controller code works but I can not get it to work when using my SP.

Here is my view:

```
$("#btn").click(function () {
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "/LO/AjaxGetCall",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
success: function (response) {
    if (response != null) {
        alert(response.Borrower);
        //$('#Borrower').val(response.Borrower);
        //$('#Type').val(response.Type);
        //$('#TypeOfLoan').val(response.TypeOfLoan);
    } else {
        alert("Something went wrong");
    }
},
failure: function (response) {
    alert(response.responseText);
},
error: function (response) {
    alert(response.responseText);
}
});
});
```

Controller that is working w/o SP:

```
public JsonResult AjaxGetCall()
{
    Loan loan = new Loan
    {
        Type = "Gnanavel Sekar",
        Borrower = "Software Engineer",
        TypeOfLoan = "Chennai"
    };
    return Json(loan, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Controller I am trying to use with SP that is giving a undefined alert error:

```
public JsonResult AjaxGetCall( string Cust)
{

List<LoanOrder> loan = new List<LoanOrder>();
string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
{
    string query = "GetCustSP";
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
    {
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Cust", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Cust;
        con.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                loan.Add(new LoanOrder
                {
                    Type = sdr["CUSTNO"].ToString(),
                    Borrower = sdr["PRTNAM"].ToString(),
                    TypeOfLoan = sdr["ADDR"].ToString(),
                });
            }
            
        }
        con.Close();
        return Json(loan, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

}
}
```